# Pass function with parameters

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

I have method:

```
fun method(number: Int, name: String){
//TODO
}
```

and I want to pass this method to class with parameters

```
class Test(
val method: KFunction2<@ParamererName(name = "number") Int,
@ParameterName(name="name") String, Unit>)
```

and I can pass it by this way

```
Test(::method)
```

but I would like to pass with params like

`Test(::method(2,"John"))` - but it doesn't work

Is it possible to pass method reference with params ? How to do it ?

Comment: Not possible. Why do you want to do that? It doesn't make sense to pass a function reference with its parameters. Just call the function with those parameters, why pass it? The whole point of passing a function reference is to be able to pass any parameters to it.

Comment: I'm just interested if it is possible, it is something like listener/callback

Comment: Already told you it's not possible unless you define them as parameters of Test. And again, why would you pass the parameters to a listener/callback reference? If you already know the parameters, just directly call the function with those parameters. What are you trying to do? Explain your context.

Comment: for example, this class Test can has logic which is responsible for when invoke this function

Comment: Ok then you can use `Test(::method, 2, "John")`.

Comment: but with this approach I have to implement additional fields in Test constructor, I thought it is possible to do it without modify Test constructor

Comment: Not possible, that's the only way. However you can write your own class and implement this feature if you want.

Comment: There are plenty of use cases for it. The function could be querying data which does not exist when the instance is created but will eventually exist, or maybe the processing of the return value is very expensive and should be delayed until (or even if) it is actually needed. Passing such a function to the constructor avoids a source-code dependency between the class and the function arguments (and of course the function implementation): the class only expects an eventual value and doesn't need to know anything other than its type.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 ways of achieving it.

If you take a `Printer` class which prints an eventual `String`

```kotlin
class Printer ( val lazyValue: () -> String ) {
    fun print () {
        println(this.lazyValue())
    }
}
```

You can hardcode the laziness into the function (meh...)

```kotlin
fun lazyNumberName(number: Int, name: String): () -> String = { ->
    "$number $name"
}

val printer = Printer(lazyNumberName(2, "john"))
printer.print()
```

You can wrap the function call in a lambda on the call site (I like this better)

```kotlin
fun numberName(number: Int, name: String): String = 
    "$number $name"

val printer = Printer({ -> numberName(2, "john")})
printer.print()
```

Or you can define a `lazy` function which makes any function lazy. I don't know Kotlin well enough to type it. Here is what it would look like in Typescript:

```
const lazy = <Args extends any[], R>(
   f: (...args: Args) => R) =>
       (...args:Args) => ():R =>
           f(...args);

const add = (a:number, b:number) => a + b;

const lazyAdd = lazy(add);

const lazyAdd_1_2 = lazyAdd(1, 2);

const three = lazyAdd_1_2();// 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking your initial example function, the class `Test` could be instantiated like following, with a function `call()` that invokes the function passed in the constructor with the two parameters

```
fun function(number: Int, name: String) {
    // function body
}

class Test(
    val action: (Int, String) -> Unit,
    val firstParam: Int,
    val secondParam: String
) {
    
    fun call() {
        action(firstParam, secondParam)
    }
}

// Usage
val test = Test(::function, 2, "John")

test.call() // invokes function(2, "John")
```